# I want to refresh the page with location.reload () and then call the function but the function only executes for a moment and disappears

Tags: javascript, html

Here are the code I am using to call the function:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    
    myCalc();

    location.reload()   
})
```

Comment: you can use `Primse` like `myCalc().then(function () { location.replad()})` what happened with you is normally because the page is already reloaded

Answer (score 1):

The execution of the script is tied to the page. If a new page is loaded (even if it is the same one), the script being executed stops. It's like having a plan "I'll detonate this nuclear bomb in my kitchen, then make breakfast". No, you won't, that's not how nuclear bombs work, and that's not how `location.reload()` works ;)

What you can do instead is make sure that there is a script being run at the page load, that responds to certain state you have saved; so that even though your previous script died, the newly loaded script knows what to do next. The easiest way to do so is likely by using `localStorage`. Or, better yet, you can build your application in such a way that a reload is not necessary: this is called a Single-Page Application (SPA).